# Multithreading private constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

Straight out from Java concurrency in Practice :

```java
@ThreadSafe
public class SafePoint {
  @GuardedBy("this") private int x, y;
  private SafePoint(int[] a) { this(a[0], a[1]); }
  public SafePoint(SafePoint p) { this(p.get()); }
  public SafePoint(int x, int y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
   }
  public synchronized int[] get() {
     return new int[] { x, y };
  }
  public synchronized void set(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

The above is a Thread-safe class : since its setters are synchronized.
I understand also why the getter doesn't individually return x / y but instead returns an array. 
I have 2 questions .
Why ?

1. `private SafePoint(int[] a)`
2. `public SafePoint(SafePoint p) { this(p.get()); }` instead of `this(p.x,p.y);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because calling `this(p.x, p.y)` is not atomic. In other words, imagine the following thread interleaving:

- Thread1: `read p.x`
- Thread2: `p.set(otherX, otherY);`
- Thread1: `read p.y` and call `this(p.x, p.y);`

The x and the y are now from two different points and possibly not consistent.

On the other hand, `p.get()` reads x and y atomically (it is `synchronized`) and therefore guarantees that the x and the y in the array are from the same point.

Comment: perfect.crystal clear! as a sidenote, since x and y are virtually entwined, what if we had a int[]location instead? or should I ask a separate question for this one?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: i mean would this class be better off,if we had an int[]loc as the instance variable, instead of x,y and this array would obviously contain the variables x,y

Comment: @anirbanchowdhury I suppose x and y are self explanatory variables in the case of a point whereas a `loc[]` array is less readable. From a thread safety perspective that would not make a difference (note that you would still need to make a copy of the array in the getter).

Comment: obviously the getter would remain unchanged,and I believe we would have to hit the synchronized getter.

Comment: class SafePoint {
  private int[] loc;
  /*made public - called 1st*/
  public SafePoint(int[] a) { this.loc = a; }
  /*this is invoked on mutation*/
  public SafePoint(SafePoint p) { this(p.get()); }
    public synchronized int[] get() {
     return Arrays.copyOf(loc,1);
  }
  public synchronized void set(int x, int y) {
   this.loc[0] = x ;
   this.loc[1] = y;
  }
}

Comment: I guess the problem with this is the code calling the constructor with the array also needs to protect the array,so that the underlying contents are not meddled with and probably thats why its private in the 1st place. What do you say? @assylias

Comment: You should make a copy of the array in your first constructor - if you don't it means that the calling code has a reference to your array which is an issue from a thread safety perspective. Apart from that it seems equivalent.